# 'Await' cannot be used inside a 'Catch' statement, a 'Finally' statement, or a 'SyncLock' statement

Tags: vb.net, async-await, catch-block

I try to reproduce logic of C# program on my VB program, all going fine except one future, VB don't allow to reproduce this construction:

```
try
{
    await nextButton[1].ClickAsync();
}
catch
{
    await nextButton[0].ClickAsync();
}
```

Of course, I can just delete Await inside catch

```
Try
    Await nextButton(1).ClickAsync()
Catch
          nextButton(0).ClickAsync()
End Try
```

But in this case I receive warning

```
Warning BC42358 Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed.
```

This is changing workflow of program, I need click asynchronously on nextButton(1) and only this click unsuccessful I need the same asynchronous operation click, but in previous button.

How to reproduce this logic on VB.NET?

Comment: Why would `nextButton[1].ClickAsync();` fail? `nextButton[0].ClickAsync();` never does? What if it does? -- You should avoid controlling the *workflow* of your app with try/catch blocks

Comment: @Jimi, for example this button disabled, or maybe newer exist in current page. But this question is more globally, then in my question, because I have another place what I want to reproduce in my VB program, and in each case I need something doing asynchronously inside catch (for example page reloading) and than wait async operation. This is useful workflow for C# programmer, but I'm mostly VB programmer (very rare in C#), therefore this is very important question for me.

Comment: @Jimi, If page does, my program need "Await Task.Delay(2000)" than goto to next URL in cycle "Await page.GoToAsync(url)" or (depends of various condition) "return Task (of MySomethingModel)"

Comment: you could use the continue with method of task and navigate in there where you then could use await. or if worse comes to worst you could the wait method.

Comment: That's useful workflow for nobody. If that, very similar code - hence subject to very similar conditions - fails in turn, your app goes to the trash can. You should return state in case the first call fails and decide what to do then. Possibly, avoid exceptions by checking beforehand that the object you're referencing exists and is not null. If it's not possible to predict the result of a call, then catch that exception and return state, if further action is needed. You cannot risk that code in a catch block throws itself in some context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do logic in the exception handler, and keep a variable indicating whether there was an exception or not. Then use that variable to determine which `nextButton.ClickAsync()` you call.

```vb
Dim success As Boolean
Try
    ' do stuff which may raise exception
    success = True
Catch
    success = False
End Try

If success Then
    Await nextButton(0).ClickAsync()
Else
    Await nextButton(1).ClickAsync()
End If
```

If `nextButton(0).ClickAsync()` raises the exception you're looking for, you can still put it in the `Try`.